# Show/Hide DIV on ASP.NET dropdown value change

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have the following dropdown on my ASP.NET page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="selectAttending" runat="server">
              <asp:ListItem Value="Select One...">Select One...</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="No">No</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

I also have the following script:

```
$(function (){
$("#selectAttending").change(function () { 
ToggleDropdown(); 
}); 
ToggleDropdown();  
}); 

function ToggleDropdown(){
if ($("#selectAttending").val() == "No") {
    $("#ifAttending").hide(); 
} 
else{
    $("#ifAttending").show(); 
 } 
};
```

The DIV tag I would like to show if they are attending is:
    #ifAttending

Do I need to add an attribute to the dropdown to show/hide on change or is the code just wrong?

Comment: Do you know that your ids are correct? `selectAttending` may have qualifiers attached to it by .net. Check the rendered page?

Comment: When you're running the application, how does the HTML ID of selectAttending is rendered? is it really just "selectAttending"?

Comment: son of a....dangit this is the second time that stumped me.  Thanks.

Comment: I had to add ClientIDMode=Static to the tags.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that selectAttending is the control id used in the ASP code behind page and not the id of the dropdown element in the html.

You'll have to do this to get the client id of the control:

```
$(function (){
    $("#<%=selectAttending.ClientID%>").change(function () { 
        ToggleDropdown(); 
    }); 
    ToggleDropdown();  
}); 

function ToggleDropdown(){
    if ($("#<%=selectAttending.ClientID%>").val() == "No") {
        $("#ifAttending").hide(); 
    } 
    else{
        $("#ifAttending").show(); 
    } 
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

You are in .net so the identifier in jquery is not #selectAttending
unless you are using clientidmode="static" if not your identifier will be in .net
selectAttending.UniqueID

Answer (score 1):

Although your code should work but you can simplify and try this code. Note that I am using jQuery `toggle` method which takes a boolean parameter to show/hide the element.

```
$(function (){
   $("#selectAttending").change(function () { 
       $("#ifAttending").toggle(this.value == "Yes")
   })
   .change();//trigger the change event on page load
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code looks about right. My guess is the ID of your `DropDownList` on the client isn't exactly `selectAttending` because of [naming containers](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-vb).

You can use a css class name, or get the ClientID with syntax like:

```
$("#<%=selectAttending.ClientID%>")
```